# boost::serialization of static array / archive exception on restore

Tags: c++, boost, deserialization

The following code compiles and seems to serialize properly (that is, the static is saved only once apparently).  However, it has an 'input stream error' exception on restore:

```
#include <boost/serialization/tracking.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/level.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>

class SA {
        std::array<char, 1024*1024> sbuf;
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int ver) {
                ar & boost::serialization::make_array(sbuf.data(), sbuf.size());
        };
};

BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(SA, boost::serialization::object_serializable);      // serialization_level
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(SA, boost::serialization::track_always);           // tracking_level

class Foo {
        char                    buf[1024];
        inline static SA        sxbuf;

        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int ver) {
                ar & boost::serialization::make_array(buf, sizeof(buf));
                ar & sxbuf;
        };
};

class FooList {
        std::array<Foo, 100>    fool;
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int ver) {
                ar & boost::serialization::make_array(fool.data(), fool.size());
        };
};

int
main()
{
        const std::string filename{"foo.sav"};
        FooList         x;

        std::ofstream   out{filename, std::ios::binary};
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(out);
        oa << x;
        std::cout << "Saved\n";

        std::ifstream   ifs{filename};
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
        if (ifs.fail()) {
                std::cerr << "couldn't open input file " << filename << "\n";
                return 1;
        }
        ia >> x;        // gives exception
        std::cout << "Restored\n";

        return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Saved
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  input stream error
```

(I tried this on godbolt too, but -lboost_serialization didn't seem to work, so it wouldn't link properly... possibly my error there).

Any insight much appreciated...

Comment: Godbolt doesn't support linking libraries (with the exception of libfmt). I use Coliru or Wandbox for these purposes.

Answer (score 0):

- This opens an archive before the writing end is finalized:

  ```
   std::ofstream out{filename, std::ios::binary};
   boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(out);
   oa << x;
   std::cout << "Saved\n";

   std::ifstream ifs{filename};
  ```

  Also `ifs` is missing the `ios::binary` flag.

Other than that, you can

- drop `make_array`,
- prefer `std::array` over `T[]` and
- default the serialization level.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b698ddde3542f6bb)**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>

#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class SA {
    std::array<char, 1024 * 1024> sbuf;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned) { ar &sbuf; }
};

BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(SA, boost::serialization::track_always) // tracking_level

class Foo {
    std::array<char, 1024> buf;
    inline static SA sxbuf;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned) { ar &buf &sxbuf; }
};

class FooList {
    std::array<Foo, 100> fool;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned) { ar &fool; }
};

int main() {
    const std::string filename{"foo.sav"};

    {
        std::ofstream out(filename, std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(out);
        FooList x{};
        oa << x;
        std::cout << "Saved\n";
    }

    {
        std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);

        FooList x{};
        ia >> x; // gives exception
        std::cout << "Restored\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Saved
Restored
```

Comment: yes, thanks.  adding out.close() after 'oa << x' seemed to do the trick also.

Comment: @kfall "seemed" is the key word there. At least /also/ let the archive finalize. (Yes this interface design is suboptimal in my view/ OTOH manual resource management is always a smell in c++)